# Why all files not showing when opening Android project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I open an Android  project,in Project tab i can see just one file by the name of external libraries and .other the file of my project like res and.. are not showing like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUkam.png).How can i fix it?

Comment: Seems like something wrong in your project structure or your project's path.

Comment: how you try to open a project ? is it a eclipse project?

Comment: Sukam avu thai chhe ena mate to tare project ni andar files paidi chhe e jovu pade.

Comment: file>open. then i select the project path.i don't know it is an eclipse project or not..i dwonloaded it..i want to open it in intellij idea.before it was opened in injtellj but now when iopen it just have external librariries file in it

Answer (score 0):

Try this if its helps:

1.If you have taken checkout or clone from `svn` or `git` respectively.Try this command to project path.

```
chmod -r 777 ./
```

2.Go to Build ->clean Project -> rebuild project